# Spring bean instantiation

Tags: spring, javabeans

Does Spring instantiate the various beans in a non-blocking way? If I do a `Thread.sleep` in the `afterPropertiesSet` of a particular bean, does this block the instantiation of other beans?

Comment: Yes it will block.